# Create Static Method to Call Method within Class for each Member of Class

Tags: javascript

I'm getting "Person.introduce" is not a function with the following code.

Essentially, what I am trying to do is:

Create a static method called introducePeople that will take in an array of Person instances.

- Have the method console.log an error message of "introducePeople only takes an array as an argument." if the argument is not of type Array.
- Have the method console.log an error message of "All items in array
  must be Person class instances." if any of the items in the array are
  not instances of the Person class.
- If there are no errors logged to
  the console, call introduce on each of the People instances in the
  input array.

```
class Person{

  firstName;
  lastName;
  age;

  constructor(firstName, lastName, age) {
    this.firstName = firstName,
    this.lastName = lastName,
    this.age = age
  }

  introduce() {
    console.log(`Hi, I'm ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}, and I'm ${this.age} years old.`);
  }


  static introducePeople(...people) {
    if (Array.isArray(people)) {
      console.error("introducePeople only takes an array as an argument.")
    } else if (!(people instanceof Person)) {
      console.error("All items in array must be Person class instances.")
    } else {
      return people
        .forEach((aPerson) => Person.introduce(aPerson))
    }
  }


};
```

I've also tried:

```
static introducePeople(...people) {
    if (!Array.isArray(people)) {
      console.log("introducePeople only takes an array as an argument.")
    } else if (!(people instanceof Person)) {
      console.log("All items in array must be Person class instances.")
    } else {
      return people
        .forEach((aPerson) => aPerson.introduce)
    }
  }
```

Which takes away the aforementioned error, however, the code does not work the way it seems it should.

Lastly, I've tried this:

```
static introducePeople(array) {
    for (const person of array) {
      if (person instanceof Person) {
        person.introduce();
      } else if (!(Array.isArray(array))) {
        console.error("introducePeople only takes an array as an argument.")
        return;
      } else {
        console.error("All items in array must be Person class instances.")
        return;
      }(!(person instanceof Person))
    }
  }
```

Which is good but it does not pass the "Must provide error message if array is not array/person is not instance of person"

Comment: And what issues are you having? In any case, check the `else if` statement in `introducePeople`, there seems to be a syntax error there.

Comment: I'm getting "Person.introduce" is not a function with the following code. If I remove the 'Person' class from it I get "introduce is not defned"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the `introduce` method as a *static method*, but `introduce` is an *instance method* that is given to each `Person` instance. Maybe you meant to call `introduce` on every person in the `people` array.

Your `if` statements won't work as expected. `...people` is **always** an array, because you explicitly said it would be with the spread operator `...`. Thats why the `if` and `else if` will never be true.

Instead loop over the `people` array and check if each item in the array is an instance of `Person`. If it is, then call the `introduce` method on the person object.

```js
class Person {
  firstName;
  lastName;
  age;

  constructor(firstName, lastName, age) {
    this.firstName = firstName,
    this.lastName = lastName,
    this.age = age
  }

  introduce() {
    console.log(`Hi, I'm ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}, and I'm ${this.age} years old.`);
  }

  static introducePeople(people) {
    if (!Array.isArray(people)) {
      throw new Error('introducePeople only takes an array as an argument.');
    }
    
    const hasValidArguments = people.every(
      person => person instanceof Person
    );
    
    if (!hasValidArguments) {
      throw new Error('All items in array must be Person class instances.');
    }
    
    for (const person of people) {
      if (person instanceof Person) {
        person.introduce();
      }
    }
  }
};

const buzz = new Person('Buzz', 'Aldrin', 46);
const neil = new Person('Neil', 'Armstrong', 42);

Person.introducePeople([buzz, neil]);
```

Comment: I appreciate the information, however, it is not currenntly passing the tests.
If you'd like to download the tests and problem ---- The Github Repo is here >[link](https://github.com/appacademy/practice-for-week-04-class-practice) @Emiel

Comment: I also just changed the ...people to plain 'array' and it now passes 1/3 of the next tests. The ones that remain are:

 1) should throw an error if input is not an array
  2) should throw an error if array does not contain instances of Person

Comment: The two remaining tests fail due to: AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw Error

Comment: Well, it's your homework. I hope you'll learn something from it.

Comment: I got it to print out the correct messages when required, some reaon it's still not passing the tests. XD if you figure it out, I'd appreciate it, until then, you unblocked me and allowed me to progress, so thank you for your time, I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use

```
 .forEach((aPerson) => aPerson.introduce())
```

because `introduce` is not a static function;

Besides, I believe the `people` param of `introducePeople`  will always be an array,  even called without params, it will be `[]`

see [MDN rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

Comment: Thanks, Ia ctually fixed that right before you commented. XD